# hyper-v on w2012 - how to clone guest multiple times with same disk and diferent machine name

Tags: hyper-v, clone, guest

I have a Win2012 R2 server with Hyper-V that have 20 virtual machines (w2003) that use a base disk and diferential ones for each one, the vms was increased size with time and I need to start fresh again.

I see that W2008 R2 VMs guest support dynamic memory and like to use them.

My question is if exist and can give me some insight on how to make a "base" VM disk and then make 20 VMs use that same disk but changing machine name, and each day delete those VMS and replicate again the base vm to not downgrade performance on them.

thanks in advance for any insights and sorry if this is a basic question, I'm a dev mainly.

Comment: I see a step by step on https://medium.com/tech-jobs-academy/how-to-use-differencing-disks-to-deploy-multiple-vms-quickly-in-hyper-v-1634f94c5541 that seems to do what I want, can someone tell me if this is the best aproach? Can I delete those created VMs and recreate again each day? thanks